# How to add custom column for previous day sales for each product in Power Query

Tags: datetime, powerquery, customcolumn

I have this table:

| Date | Product | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/3/2021 | Apple | 10 |
| 1/3/2021 | Lemon | 20 |
| 1/3/2021 | Mango | 30 |
| 1/4/2021 | Apple | 15 |
| 1/4/2021 | Lemon | 25 |
| 1/5/2021 | Apple | 20 |
| 1/5/2021 | Lemon | 20 |
| 1/5/2021 | Mango | 35 |

And I want to add a new column like this:

| Date | Product | Sales | **Prev Day Sales** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/3/2021 | Apple | 10 | *null* |
| 1/3/2021 | Lemon | 20 | *null* |
| 1/3/2021 | Mango | 30 | *null* |
| 1/4/2021 | Apple | 15 | 10 |
| 1/4/2021 | Lemon | 25 | 20 |
| 1/5/2021 | Apple | 20 | 15 |
| 1/5/2021 | Lemon | 20 | 25 |
| 1/5/2021 | Mango | 35 | *null* |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a column with previousDate and then join the table itself by Date-PreviousDate fields, then extract only the Sales field an rename it at wish.

This should be null for days where no sales had taken place in the previous date.

Add a custom column with previous date as Date.AddDays([Date],-1) Then, in Home/Transform/Merge queries and select the same table to merge. Select the "Previous Date" field from the original and merge with the "Date" field on the second. Then CTRL-Click the field "Product" to use it also in the merge. Use a left outer join, so no rows are added. Expand the Sales column in the merged result and, here you go!
Greetings!

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how to do the join?
Thanks!

Comment: I tried to join the the table itself, but it didn't work since for each date there are more than 1 product.

Comment: Of course!
Add a custom column with previous date as Date.AddDays([Date],-1)
Then, in Home/Transform/Merge queries and select the same table to merge. Select the "Previous Date" field from the original and merge with the "Date" field on the second. Then CTRL-Click the field "Product" to use it also in the merge. Use a left outer join, so no rows are added. Expand the Sales column in the merged result and, here you go!

Comment: You have to merge using two fields. In the merge queries popup you can choose the second (and third, and fourth...) by ctrl-clicking any number of fields. In your example, dates and products are the required to obtain your result

Comment: It worked! Could you edit your answer above (just copy-paste your comments), so that I can accept your answer and mark this question as solved?